# ¿Son aceptables las ediciones solo para llamar la atención de tu pregunta/respuesta?

Tags: discusión

Pues me di cuenta de esto ahora estando en SO en Español ya que por la cantidad de posts que hay en SO no le di la importancia debida.

Sin ánimos de hacerle publicidad a mi pregunta (de la cual necesito una respuesta desesperadamente) [¿Cómo centrar una tabla con respecto al ancho del documento?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387/c%C3%B3mo-centrar-una-tabla-con-respecto-al-ancho-del-documento), ¿es válido hacer ediciones mínimas, digamos agregar un punto al final de un párrafo o agregar un tag nuevo (como en mi caso que agregué [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)) para hacer aparecer tu pregunta/respuesta en el feed de actividades?

Mi pregunta ya estaba bien abajo y con la edición, pues se fue para arriba, y se me ocurrió que este tipo de cosas se pueden hacer deliberadamente con la intención de jalar el ojo a los demás:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué opinan?

Comment: la mayoria de los sitios funcionan asi. si quieres ver las preguntas nuevas unicamente puedes pulsar el boton "preguntas" luego en "recientes".

Comment: La verdad es que nunca me he topado con ese tipo de *bump*, pero lo tengo claro: voto negativo si necesario y reportar a los moderadores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. En general, lo que propones (hacer *bumping* de un post), se considera mala *netiqueta*.

En particular, en Stack Exchange, <strike>hay</strike>había unos límites de ediciones, tras los cuales un post se <strike>convierte</strike>convertía automáticamente en wiki, para evitar este comportamiento.

Aunque esto ya no es así, si un post es editado más de 10 veces por su autor, es reportado automáticamente a los moderadores, para que decidan si deben hacer algo al respecto; que, según lo que dice [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) en esta [respuesta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293827/371250) en [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) a la pregunta [How many edits automatically turn my answer into a Community Wiki answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293826/how-many-edits-automatically-turn-my-answer-into-a-community-wiki-answer), puede ser:

- desestimar el caso si las ediciones eran sustanciales
- dejar un comentario pidiendo que en adelante las ediciones sean sustanciales
- dejar un mensaje con un aviso amistoso si hay indicaciones de que las ediciones eran simplemente para reclamar atención.

Del mismo modo, los usuarios con 10K de reputación (o 2K en sitios en beta) pueden ver una lista de los posts recientes que se hayan editado más veces (excluyendo los marcados como wiki).

Pero eso no significa que no puedas editar tu post. Lo que significa es que si editas tu post debe ser para mejorarlo, no para reclamar atención. Una opción para reclamar atención sobre tu post sería pasarte por el chat.

Comment: En realidad en stackoverflow ya no hay límite de ediciones desde abril del 2014: [How many edits automatically turn my answer into a Community Wiki answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293827/186133) y [Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947/137182)

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz: gracias por el aviso, ahora edito.

Answer (score 2):

Si una edición es mínima o no es un poco subjetivo.

- Agregar o quitar un tag nunca es una modificación mínima pues la idea es de clasificar mejor la pregunta.
- Correcciones ortográficas suelen ser bienvenidas ya que a nadie le gustaría una comunidad donde la ortografía fuera realmente deprimente. Sin embargo se debe tratar de corregir todas las fallas de una vez ya que solo modificar un caracter podría parecer que se esta tratando de justamente llamar la atención.

De todas formas "llamar la atención" haciendo una pequeña modificación no es muy efectiva. Por ahora que el sitio tiene pocas preguntas y se están respondiendo activamente dudo mucho que algunas preguntas se estén quedando en el olvido.

Y cuando el sitio ya tenga bastante tráfico, igualmente las preguntas no van a durar mucho en el home page ya que van a ser empujada rápidamente por las nuevas. Depende mucho el algoritmo de ordenamiento de stackoverflow que involucra los tags tanto favoritos como ignorados y los tags al cual uno tiene mas reputación

**En conclusión**: Si la edición es mínima o no, no es tan relevante ya que de todas maneras no se puede hacer mucho mas que rechazar las ediciones si las ven en la cola de revisión

Comment: Es cierto lo que dices, cuando haya mayor tráfico no pasará esto y se convertiría en una acción sin sentido